# How to add Tab bar and navigation bar in subviews using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

[Please refer the image, where I have used the Navigation Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcoJJ.png)I tried surfing all over, but could not get the solution. Also, I am new to swift, so kindly help! I have a view controller -- Login page, which is connected to an another view controller-- CoreView.swift. I have created 5 subviews in CoreView ViewController. I want to add a Tab Bar where, user can click on the images of the Tab Bar and the corresponding subview should get open. Also, help me to add the images as the subview icon. the icon does not get displayed.

Also, when I try to put the back button from navigation controller, I can set the Title and prompt message, but not the back button in sub views, why so?

Thanks!

[Look at this image to see the code and the xib file made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5bSV.png)

I have the following changes. but still no luck..

Comment: Looks like what you need is a "tab bar controller". For every controller that you link to the tab bar controller you can set up a custom image and a title. Second thing, for back button you need a bar item.

Comment: @Andrej, I did that. I also, tried including the tab bar controller , not to the initial view controller, but to the view controller where i want the Tab Bar to be seen, but it did not worked. And, regarding the back button, I even tried doing that programmatically, nothing helped so far.Can you suggest me what to do?

Comment: In the linked image you're trying to add a navigation bar to a "UIView", not "UIViewController", there fore if you implement any sort of back button it wont work. What you can do is trigger an action and then manually dismiss / pop view controller. But I would not recommend that. I would recommend that you embed a view controller in navigation controller.

Comment: @Andrej, Thanks for your reply:). But, I want to add the back buttons on the sub views. I dont need that for the view controller. can you please suggest me any way out?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the navigation bar -> you should be able to just drat and drop the UIButton into your left bar button item:

[image]

EDIT: updated image to actually show xib implementation.

EDIT2: to link the button use this:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("Back button tapped")
}
```

Make sure to connect the button in your interface builder to your custom view. You need to have a custom UIView subclass and should be chosen for your File's owner.

Comment: Can you help me what should be the main line of code to programmatically call the bak button?

Comment: Sir, I am very new to swift. Can you please elaborate? Are you asking me to make an inner class in UIViewController as Class CustomView: UIView     ?